# sqlite3 not being linked to my IOS project

Tags: objective-c, database, xcode, sqlite, ios6

I am currently working to link an sqlite3 db to my ios project. I have created the project as a single view application. ![enter image description here][1] as you can see in the image below I have my set frameworks and my database file. However when I type in the #import "./usr/include/sqlite3.h" it says that the file is not found.

What I'm trying to do is create a database that holds roughly about 100 items. Personally I did not want to use CoreData and this was the simplest way of setting up the db. If anyone has a suggestion on how to set this dd it would be greatly appreciated.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
***#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"***

@interface databaseViewController :UIViewController { 
    UITextField     *name;
    UITextField *address;
    UITextField *phone;
    UILabel *status;
    NSString        *databasePath;
    sqlite3 *contactDB;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *address;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phone;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;
- (IBAction) saveData;
- (IBAction) findContact;
@end
```

Comment: You need to add, I'm thinking, `libsqlite3` to your project.  I don't have Xcode here to look, but you select the project in the left-hand column, then on the first or second page of project properties, at the bottom, is a list of static libraries you're using.  Click "+", then find 'libsqlite3" in the list to be added.  Or something like that.

Comment: thanks for the input we already have the sqlite added and we are still receiving this error. I wanted to upload screenshot but it does not let me. Do you know of any tutorials I would try to build a db from scratch but the liability on that is pretty high.

Comment: You shouldn't be importing the .h with the "/usr/include" prefix.

Comment: you should quit your xcode also first and restart xcode..

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the code

```
#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
```

should also work, but anyway it is incorrect to use this approach. The correct way is to include like this:

```
#import <sqlite3.h>
```

So Xcode will always search for the header in the appropriate SDK currently used to build project.
And don't forget to add libsqlite3 to a linked libraries section of your target.

Answer (score 2):

To get best tutorial for iphone Sqlite Database connectivity you can click [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977973/iphonehow-to-use-sqlite-connectivity-in-iphone):

And add libsqlite3.dylib to your project. Then add #import "sqlite3.h" in .h file of your class in which you have to use sqlite.. For more detail you can revert me..

Answer (score 0):

add libsqlite3.tbd on your project

select your TARGETS > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries

> add libsqlite3.tbd

[image]

I've got xcode7